# How to calculate a value based on the similarity of two strings

Tags: python, nlp

I have two strings where I want to find a value based on the similar  word occurrence among these two strings

```
actual = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'student', 'from', 'computer', 'science', 'department']
predicted = ['computer', 'and', 'science', 'department']
```

Above are sample two string I wants to compare.

Ex : There are 3 similar words occurred in `predicted` string when compared to `actual` string

Expected output I want to get is the length of the actual & predicted strings and the similar occurrences(words) which is 3 in this case

```
length of actual = 8
length of predicted = 4
similar word count = 3
```

Comment: Did you at least try some approach? It's a trivial problem just iterate through both strings, compare each and increment a variable 'match' when you find a equal values.

Comment: The first two lines of the expected output are trivial, and the third line isn't much harder.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: "and the similar occurrences(words) " => do you actually mean "similar" or "equal"?

Comment: Actually I want a value to be generated when compared to the output values wrt NLP . I need an answer on that aspect

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to convert `actual` and `predicted` into sets and then construct the intersection of both. Note however that this does not work for multiple occurrences, as sets do not contain duplicates, so the similar word count for `actual = ['computer', 'computer', 'computer']` and `predicted = ['computer', 'computer', 'computer']` is 1.

```
actual = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'student', 'from', 'computer', 'science', 'department']
predicted = ['computer', 'and', 'science', 'department']

print("length of actual = ", len(actual))
print("length of predicted = ", len(predicted))
print("similar word count = ", len(set(actual).intersection(set(predicted))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[linuskmr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903716/17769815) is pretty good if you only want to count the same word once in the similarity calculation.

However, if you want to be able to count the same word multiple times, you can use `collections.Counter` rather than sets. You can find the words that appear in both lists using `&` along with the minimum of the counts for that word between those two lists. The actual word counts are stored in the values of the counter, and we want to find the total number of common occurrences, so we use `.values()` and `sum()`:

```py
from collections import Counter

result = sum((Counter(actual) & Counter(predicted)).values())

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
3
```